# Making a basic algorithm

Tags: java

So basically I want to find a easier way to do this:

```
 if(size == 2 || size == 6 || size == 10 || size == 14 || ...) unit /= 2;
```

So basically it start at 2 and then it check if equals to previous size + 4.

I need to go up to 256.

I want to know if there a easy way of doing this.

EDIT: Sorry I meant to do it all in one line, not multiple lines.

Comment: to confirm, it is invariant for size == 3, for example?

Comment: @Bathsheba yes it is invariant

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly (at least for this example): if `size` is `2` then you want to divide unit 3 times (2^3 -> divide by 8), if size is `6` then divide unit 2 times (divide by 4) and `10` divide once (divide by 2)?

Comment: It's always dividing by 2. The only thing that changing is that it checking if size is equal to previous + 4. So the next line would add if size == 14. It will always divide by 2

Comment: If size is 248 and unit is 100, will unit become 50 (`100 / 2`), or will it become 12.5 (`100 / 2 / 2 / 2`)?

Comment: Sorry I was reading the question wrong, question has been updated.

Comment: @ShawnSmith your old question was better. Let's solve that one instead.

Comment: @ShawnSmith - This is not the same question now. In the old question a `6` would have resulted in `unit /= 4`, now it is `unit /= 2`!

Comment: Completely changing the question is an inconsiderate thing to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions that are constantly changing are impossible to answer.

Comment: @P45Imminent well said that man

Answer (score 5):

You may do this:

```
if ( size >= 2 && size <= 256 && size % 4 == 2 ) 
    unit /= 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If it keeps getting raised by 4, you could try using module-4:

```
if ((size - 2) % 4 == 0 && size <= 256){
    unit /= 2;
}
```

Or, if `size` can be negative but should be positive:

```
if ((size - 2) % 4 == 0 && size >= 0 && size <= 256){
    unit /= 2;
}
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Corrected, thanks. Forgot that `0 % N = 0`.

Comment: Sorry I was reading the question wrong, question has been updated.

Comment: @ShawnSmith With your updated question my code should work.

Comment: Almost, it goes up to 256, so you need a ```&& size <= 256```

Comment: Not quite - you need to check the range too.

Comment: it does what it did before when I was doing it in multiple lines. Saying that, it doesn't work with the updated question.

Comment: @AndyTurner You're indeed correct, edited. And I agree, his "old" question was a more interesting problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can ace this in O(1) with

```
if ((size - 2) % 4 == 0){
    /*2, 6, 10 etc*/    
    unit >>= (Math.min(size, 256) + 2) / 4;
}
```

where the bitwise shift generates the appropriate multiplication of a power of two: a touchstone for your knowledge of operator precedences.

Now the question has been updated, the operation on `unit` is the considerably duller `unit /= 2`, and you'll have to add in the newly-introduced upper-bound on size of `256`.

Comment: Dividing and left shifting? Also, if size is 2, unit is divided by a lot more than 2...

Comment: @AndyTurner: we'll publish jointly.

Comment: I think you want something more like `(258 - size) / 4` - for size 2, you should halve 64 times; for size 254 you should have just once.

Comment: It recovers the 2, 6, and 10 cases adequately; perhaps the OP can confirm?

Comment: Sorry I was reading the question wrong, question has been updated.

Comment: What a shame :-) this answer was so pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do it with a switch statement as follows:

```
switch(size) {
    case 2:
        unit /=2;
    case 4:
        unit /= 2;
    ....
}
```

but this is still cumbersome. Another alternative could be:

```
for(int i=2; i < 256; i+=4) {
    if (size == i) {    
        unit /= 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was reading the question wrong, question has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use an array of possible divisors.

Extend this into a `class` if the number to be divided by changes.

Derive the divisor on the fly if there is a mathematical progression of some kind (such as `d[n+1] = d[n] + 4`).

```
int[] divisors = {2, 6, 10};

int doIt(int n, int unit) {
    for (int i : divisors) {
        if (n == i) {
            unit /= 2;
        }
    }
    return unit;
}
```

Comment: size is always increasing until 256. It doesn't stop at 10.

Comment: @ShawnSmith - By a fixed amount (4?) each time? If so you need the second part of uniknow's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36601614/823393).

Comment: Sorry I was reading the question wrong, question has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

A cryptic way of doing it:

```
unit >>= ((size & -253) == 2) ? 1 : 0;
```

Explanation:

- A number in the range 2-254 is also in the range 0-255. You can do a bitwise AND with `~255 = 0xffffff00`; if the value is non-zero, it is outside that range;
- To check calculate `number % 4`, do a bitwise AND with `3`; compare this to 2 to see if `number % 4 == 2`.

So, to check if a number meets both of these criteria, we can calculate the bitwise AND of `size` with the bitwise AND of the two bit masks above: if both conditions are met, the result is 2.

Hence:

```
(size & (~255 | 3)) == 2   (simplifies to)   (size & -253) == 2.
```